# CSS3 animations - how to make different animations to different elements on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, animation, web, scroll

I have a question about the doing CSS3 animations on scroll..

I found a code, that shows the DIV element after the user scrolls down:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {

        /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
        $(window).scroll( function(){

            /* Check the location of each desired element */
            $('.hideme').each( function(i){

                var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
                var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

                /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
                if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

                    $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

                }

            }); 

        });

    });

    </script>
```

I'm building a site, which one will have about 5 different boxes, which one will be shown when the user scrolls down to each box.
But my question is, how i make the animation inside those boxes.

Foe example: in each box there is title, content and images. How do i make all the elements appear after each other, because with this code all the class elements are shown at once. 
But i would like that if user scrolls down, first the tittle appears, then the content and at the end the images.

And then when user scrolls to the next box, the same process repeat's itself.

I use some CSS3 delays, but in this case i don't know how long will user take to scroll down.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy. You would first have to make sure the title, the images, and the content are within their own `div`s. Then you would do the same process, but with the ypositions and heights of the individual divs instead. [Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WFms6/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        $('.title').each(function (i) {
            var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
                $(this).animate({
                    'opacity': '1'
                }, 500);
            }
        });
        $('.innerImage').each(function (i) {
            var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
                $(this).animate({
                    'opacity': '1'
                }, 500);
            }
        });
        $('.content').each(function (i) {
            var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
                $(this).animate({
                    'opacity': '1'
                }, 500);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: If you want the content to show when half of it is visible or something like that you could change `var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();` to `var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight()/2;`. It's very easy to customize it

Comment: aha ok, awesome :D i like the solution. And yes i already wanted to ask you, because it looks a lot better if u scroll to the middle, before the elements are shown! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution with [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)'s callback function and [.getBoundingClientRect()](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t21) function:

HTML

```html
<div style="height:1200px; background:#fef;">test</div>
    <div class="hideme">
        <div class="title">title 1</div>
        <div class="main">content 1
            <img src="/favicon.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

JS

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(window).on('scroll resize', function () {
    var win_height = $(window).height();
    $('.hideme').each(function (i) {
      var elem_pos = this.getBoundingClientRect();
      var title = $('.title',this);
      var main = $('.main',this);
      var images = $('img',this);
      if ((elem_pos.top>win_height || elem_pos.bottom<0)) {
        title.css('opacity',0); // hide title
        main.css('opacity',0); // hide contents
        images.css('opacity',0); // hide images
        return true; // below or above viewport, continue
      }
      if (title.is(':animated') || main.is(':animated') || images.is(':animated')) {
        return true; // continue
      }
      title.animate({
        'opacity': 1
      }, 500, function(){
        main.animate({
          'opacity': 1
        }, 500, function(){
          images.animate({
            'opacity' :1
          },500);
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BAf5b/3/) / [fullscreen view](http://jsfiddle.net/BAf5b/3/show/)

Comment: Interesting trick with your `var title = $('.title', this);`. I'll have to remember that

Comment: @Zeaklous Yes it's equivalent to `$(this).find('.title');`

Comment: ok quick question? If i want to run this animation just on first time the user visits the page, i need to remove what?

And second question, because i'm new to this, if i want to add another element i add it in the css and then also here var element = $('.element',this); and in if row and animate row right

Comment: to show the elements only once, it can be simplified like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BAf5b/4/

Comment: ok last question. The elements are shown before the user scrolls down to the box. In my coe the user needed to scroll down to the whole box and then the elements were show. Is there a way to show element when users scrolls to the middle of the box or something like that. Or maybe i just make the fade-in longer, because right now before the user scrolls down the elements are already shown.

Comment: @DeanDeey Yes it can be done. Only changed this condition: `if ((elem_pos.top > win_height/2 || elem_pos.bottom < win_height/2))` and now the div starts to appear when its top or bottom borders are in the middle of screen: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BAf5b/5) or [fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/BAf5b/5/show)

Comment: Thanks! You are the best. Btw the last question, why if i add another element for example ".test" to code, so i'll have 4 elements then : title, main, img and test, the code stops working.

Comment: Thanks but I am not the best. Can you please update the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BAf5b/5)? To see what doesn't work.